# what really get cached in dispatcher in cq5?

Tags: caching, aem

We Developed Header & Footer for our site. we created a content hierarchy and from a java service class we accessed content hierarchy and for each level there is a java bean to hold the values

```
For ex
 LevelOneBean.java 
   { 
     string linkName; String linkUrl, List<LevelTwoBean> LeveltwoBeanList;
   }
 LevelTwoBean.java 
   { 
     string linkName; String linkUrl, List<LevelTwoBean> LevelthreeBeanList;
   }
  LevelThreeBean.java 
   { 
     string linkName; String linkUrl, 
   }
```

After that i am rendering bean in my component jsp.

when we deployed on web server, found that these two component using  70% of cpu and hence it is slow. we do have dispatcher and page should get cached in dispatcher.
**My senior said since you have created java bean and java bean not get cached. and he asked to create JSON for header and footer. Json will get chached at dispatcher level.Java bean not.**

My Q - I want to validate my above statement statement. Ideally page get should cached regardless of rendering design.

Please help to understand this.

Answer (score 0):

Calling a bean is irrelevant here. Beans are generally called during transformation of the JCR section to HTML/CSS/JS.

If you are calling the bean during the JSP transformation phase, and then serving HTML based upon the bean results, the response should be cached.

If the browser has been served with the page, and you are making an AJAX call, a JSON or XML request is made, which can be set to cache. By default, JSON and XML are not configured to cache in a dispatcher.

The JSON call back from the dispatcher would hit the publisher, and then the JSP would call your bean to render the response. Again, it should not have anything to do with your bean.

The only thing to be careful of when you're caching, is what actions trigger to flush or clear your cache. If you are updating content, the stats file flush approach of the dispatcher works well. The danger with JSON and XML, is that you are likely to be synthesizing the response from several different source points in the tree, which if they do not match between the content and the json path, the cache is likely to not be flushed unless if you are using Dispatcher Flush for ACS commons.

https://adobe-consulting-services.github.io/acs-aem-commons/features/dispatcher-flush-rules.html

From what you have described, your bolded statement does not make sense. I would check to see what you are producing as a rendered artefact, and whether those artefacts are being cached/flushed.

Comment: Most relevant to this question - beans (and other Java tech) are called to create JSON too. And once created it could be cached in the  so that subsequent requests are served by the Dispatcher instead of the Publisher. As the answer points out, this isn't the default, but understaning that it could be maybe clarifies the problem. You can prevent **any** code from executing on the publisher by caching its results in the dispatcher.